# App service cannot access Managed Identity in C# .net 7 app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-appservice

I am trying to get the managed identity (user assigned) with the

```
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = "my-managed-id-client-id"
            });
```

which gives me the error in app insights:

```
Code: generalException
Message: An error occurred sending the request.
 ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Content:


Headers:
Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2023 12:29:17 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-CORRELATION-ID: REDACTED
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot Service request failed.
Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Content:


Headers:
Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2023 12:29:17 GMT
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-CORRELATION-ID: REDACTED
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

When following the troubleshooting instruction given here
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#azure-app-service-and-azure-functions-managed-identity

I only receive:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80 after 1 ms: Bad access
'api-version' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The two environment variables MSI_ENDPOINT and MSI_SECRET seem to be set.

So I have no more idea what to check. Anybody experienced the same?

Comment: And this code is running inside the App Service? Not on your local machine? Also could you try using ManagedIdentityCredential directly instead of DefaultAzureCredential?

Comment: yes it's running within the app service and the curl error I get within the ssh shell of the web service.

Comment: The 169.. IP address only works inside Azure VMs. App Service uses a slightly different approach where the URL is in the MSI_ENDPOINT environment variable. That instruction seems wrong to me on that page :\

Comment: I have a PowerShell version how to get the token manually here: https://joonasw.net/view/get-managed-identity-access-token-in-azure-app-service-through-kudu. Also official docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Cdotnet#rest-endpoint-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it up and running, not a 100% sure what the initial error was, but here some insights I gained:

The curl statement posted here by Microsoft is wrong:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#azure-app-service-and-azure-functions-managed-identity

In App Services, the IP 127.0.0.1 is used with an individualized port. To identify it, open the Advanced Tools on the App Service and select Environment there.

You should be able to identify the four variables:
MSI_ENDPOINT
MSI_SECRET
IDENTITY_ENDPOINT
IDENTITY_HEADER

The two Endpoint Variables indicate the address and port used.

Next thing I realized (with the help of application insights) are the error codes I received on the DefaultAzureCredential() Method:

- Error code 500: means you passed in a wrong endpoint. In my case I initially had

```
new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes: new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.send" });
```

This however, caused the error, while

```
new GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes: new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
```

works just fine.

- Error code 400: This means the id passed if using a user assigned managed identity is wrong.

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
{
    ManagedIdentityClientId = "my-managed-id-client-id"
});
```

As at some point, I had no more ideas where to look for the initial error, I started trying differen parameters. So I ended up using the ObjectId instead of the ClientId here - which (luckily) did not work. Still noting it here, as it may be helpful for somebody mixing it up in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure this in following way:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
```

Passing client id via `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` environment variable.